# form_for validation it doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following form_for to reset password.

```
<% provide(:title, "Reiniciar Password") %>

<%= form_for(@user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) ) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages'%>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            &nbsp
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="login-box">  
            <div id="login-controls">
                <%= link_to(image_tag("logo.png"), root_path) %>
                <br>
                <br>
                    <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Contrasena", :tabindex => 1, :style => "height:25px;" %>
                    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder => "Contrasena", :tabindex => 2, :style => "height:25px;" %>
                    <%= f.button "<i class=\"icon-lock icon-white\"></i> Actualizar Password".html_safe, :tabindex => 2,  class: "btn btn-warning", :style => "width:220px;margin-bottom:5px;" %>
<% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
        </div>
    </div>
```

everything works perfect, exect the validations, if you press the buttom with out type anything on the password and password_confirmation field, the controller reset the password with a blank password. In my model I have the validation for the password and password confirmation and it works when you create a new user, but I don't know why in this form for reset the password it doesn't work.

Here is the model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.new_record? && a.password.blank? }

    def send_password_reset
        self.password_reset_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
        self.password_reset_at = Time.zone.now
        save!
        UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
    end

    def reset_password_token
        self.password_reset_token = nil
        self.password_reset_at = nil
        save!
    end

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

Thank for your help.

---

UPDATE

here is the controler

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController

    layout "sessions"

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email!(params[:password_resets][:email] )
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Las instrucciones para reestrablecer la contrasena fueron enviadas."
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    if @user.password_reset_at < (2.hours.ago).to_date
        redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "El link para actualizar la contrasena ha expirado."
    elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        @user.reset_password_token
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "La contrasena ha sido cambiada."
    else
        render :edit
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: can you post controller's code ?

Comment: Sure pjam, I just posted the controller. Thanks

Comment: your problem appears with wich action on the controller ? I mean when you're submitting your form, wich action is called in the controller ? create or update ?

Comment: the update action. the create action, creates the token and sent the email with the url to reset the password, then the link, open the a form with the view and edit action, them when you press submit the update action is executed, (reset the password and erase the token). but if you click submit with out write anything on the fields the update action is execute.

Comment: this is not your original question, but in your update method, shouldn't it be `if @user.password_reset_at > (2.hours.ago).to_date`, I'm not fluent in spanish, but it seems this condition is "Link is expired", so the condition is met when `@user.password_reset_at` is greater than `2.hours.ago` ? (I'm still trying to figure out the cause of your original problem ...)

Comment: Sorry, no. For example the token was generated at 2:00pm if you try to reset you password between 2pm and 4pm, you would reset your password if no, you have to request another link to reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the cause of your problem :

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.new_record? && a.password.blank? }
```

This line skips the validation if the password is blank, so this is why your user is being saved without any password

Comment: No pjam, if I change this line like this: validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true, when I try to create the token and send the email to the user with the create action of the PasswordResetsController I get the following error: Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)

Comment: Isn't it what you want ? the validation to fail when password is blank ?

Comment: Yes, but if I commented the procedure I wouldn't  reset the password, because the model try update all the attributes of the model and throw me this this error Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), so I can generate the token for the link and send the email to the user with the link to reset the password :S

Comment: I mean: so I CAN'T generate the token for the link and send the email to the user with the link to reset the password

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you're explaining. But from what I understand, your original problem was that the validation was not preventing the user to change its password to a blank one, and now it does, so I don't get what your problem is now

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about my english. Let me try again :s in my PasswordResetsController I have 4 action. The create action generates a password_reset_token, password_reset_at and send and email. If I delete this procedure Proc.new { |a| !a.new_record? && a.password.blank? } in my model, the create action in my PasswordResetsController generate this error

Comment: You get the exception because you're using `save!`, if you don't want any exceptions to be raised, just use `save`

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in PasswordResetsController#create

Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)

So I need this procedure to skip the password validation when I create the token to reset the password. But if I use this procedure, when I try to reset the password using the update action of the PasswordResetsController the form skip the presence validation, but I need it when I'm reseting the password

Answer (score 0):

I think your proc skips password validation in case of update:

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true, 
    unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.new_record? && a.password.blank? }
```

would validate unless the record is not new (update) and the password is blank (did not submit anything in the field). Can you try commenting out the proc and see what happens?

e.g.

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your Proc Block which checks if the model is not a new record and if the password is empty. In this case the validation does not happen.

```
unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.new_record? && a.password.blank? }
```

So if you have a already created User:

```
!a.new_record? = true
```

and since the password is not saved directly but as a crypted password (password_digest) will also be nil thus:

```
a.password.blank? = true
```

So editing an existing user with this validation will not validate the password / password_confirm

At least I think so ;)

Maybe you can change it to:

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true, :if => :password?
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys the problem was on the model. Here is the new validation.

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, confirmation: true, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.new_record? && a.password.blank? && a.password_reset_token.blank? }
```

Thanks for your help and your time!